# jquery blueimp ajax isn't showing the files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I've follow the MySQL Integration of blueimp jquery file upload, however after the file has been uploaded, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 1
```

The images aren't listing but they are uploaded.

This is my JS file:

```
// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    // url:                     'teste/',
    url:                    'http://localhost/site/admin/custom-upload/upload-image',
    sequentialUploads:      true,
    previewMaxWidth:        150,
    previewMaxHeight:       150,
    previewCrop:            true,
    previewThumbnail:       true,
    loadImageMaxFileSize:   20000000, // 10MB

    imageMaxWidth:          1000,
    imageMaxHeight:         1000,

    imageMinWidth:          1000,
    imageMinHeight:         1000,
    disableImageResize:     false,

    maxNumberOfFiles:       4,

    imageCrop:              true,
    acceptFileTypes:        /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,

}).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    data.formData = data.context.find(':input').serializeArray();
});

// Load existing files:
$('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');

// Listar Imagens
$.ajax({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url:                    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
    dataType:               'json',
    context:                $('#fileupload')[0]
}).always(function (result) {
    $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
}).done(function (result) {
    $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
        .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
});
```

Response from fileupload function :

```
{"files":[{"name":"gaming-wallpapers-15.jpg","size":385236,"url":"http:\/\/localhost\/infsite-new\/public\/site\/uploads\/files\/gaming-wallpapers-15.jpg","mediumUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/infsite-new\/public\/site\/uploads\/files\/medium\/gaming-wallpapers-15.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/infsite-new\/public\/site\/uploads\/files\/thumbnail\/gaming-wallpapers-15.jpg","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/infsite-new\/admin\/custom-upload\/upload-image?file=gaming-wallpapers-15.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"}]}{"files":[{"name":"gaming-wallpapers-15.jpg","size":385236,"url":"http:\/\/localhost\/infsite-new\/public\/site\/uploads\/files\/gaming-wallpapers-15.jpg","mediumUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/infsite-new\/public\/site\/uploads\/files\/medium\/gaming-wallpapers-15.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/infsite-new\/public\/site\/uploads\/files\/thumbnail\/gaming-wallpapers-15.jpg","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/infsite-new\/admin\/custom-upload\/upload-image?file=gaming-wallpapers-15.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"}]}
```

I don't know why the images aren't listing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your JSON response is invalid, it has multiple roots, meaning you have: `{...}{...}{...}` or is that an error in writing the question?

Comment: Well I don't know how to debugg with fileupload, however I tried in a different php structure and it worked, someone please close the question.

Comment: @Thavo I'm having trouble with a very similar implementation. Did you ever figure this out? I'd like to select photos from a previous upload using the same UL template etc and would like to chat with someone familiar with the blueimp jQuery File Upload